# mi bot de discord repite todo despues de mi

Tags: python, discord.py, bot

mi  bot de discord esta repitiendo cosas hasta cosas que no son comandos haciendolo molesto la verdad no lo quiero eliminar aunque sea facil de hacer pero es bastante molesto que repita todo lo que dices porfa ayuda
posdata:el codigo esta en python

Comment: Saludos, bienvenido/a a SOes, aquí unas lecturas sugeridas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour + https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Edita la pregunta y agrega todo lo que sea necesario para que cualquier usuario pueda reproducir tu código.